# Error compiling with maven

Tags: maven

When I try to compile a maven project(Java), I get this error. It has been compiled with the following command: `mvn clean install -e(Print all errors) -l(save the log file)`

```
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building CardinalPGM 1.0-DEV
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for in.parapengu:commons:jar:1.1.2 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[WARNING] The POM for com.comphenix.executors:BukkitExecutors:jar:1.0.0 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ CardinalPGM ---
[INFO] Deleting c:\Users\Admin\Desktop\CardinalPGM-master\target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ CardinalPGM ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ CardinalPGM ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 222 source files to c:\Users\Admin\Desktop\CardinalPGM-master\target\classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] COMPILATION WARNING : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] /c:/Users/Admin/Desktop/CardinalPGM-master/src/main/java/in/twizmwaz/cardinal/cycle/Cycle.java: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
[WARNING] /c:/Users/Admin/Desktop/CardinalPGM-master/src/main/java/in/twizmwaz/cardinal/cycle/Cycle.java: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
[WARNING] /c:/Users/Admin/Desktop/CardinalPGM-master/src/main/java/in/twizmwaz/cardinal/module/modules/gamerules/GamerulesBuilder.java: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
[WARNING] /c:/Users/Admin/Desktop/CardinalPGM-master/src/main/java/in/twizmwaz/cardinal/module/modules/gamerules/GamerulesBuilder.java: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
[INFO] 4 warnings 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] error reading C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\in\parapengu\commons\1.1.2\commons-1.1.2.jar; error in opening zip file
[ERROR] error reading C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\com\comphenix\executors\BukkitExecutors\1.0.0\BukkitExecutors-1.0.0.jar; error in opening zip file
[ERROR] error reading C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\in\parapengu\commons\1.1.2\commons-1.1.2.jar; error in opening zip file
[ERROR] error reading C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\com\comphenix\executors\BukkitExecutors\1.0.0\BukkitExecutors-1.0.0.jar; error in opening zip file
[ERROR] /c:/Users/Admin/Desktop/CardinalPGM-master/src/main/java/in/twizmwaz/cardinal/module/modules/regions/type/CylinderRegion.java:[3,34] package in.parapengu.commons.utils does not exist
[ERROR] /c:/Users/Admin/Desktop/CardinalPGM-master/src/main/java/in/twizmwaz/cardinal/module/modules/gameScoreboard/GameObjectiveScoreboardHandler.java:[3,34] package in.parapengu.commons.utils does not exist
[ERROR] /c:/Users/Admin/Desktop/CardinalPGM-master/src/main/java/in/twizmwaz/cardinal/module/modules/wools/WoolObjectiveBuilder.java:[3,34] package in.parapengu.commons.utils does not exist
[ERROR] /c:/Users/Admin/Desktop/CardinalPGM-master/src/main/java/in/twizmwaz/cardinal/module/modules/kit/KitBuilder.java:[3,34] package in.parapengu.commons.utils does not exist
[ERROR] /c:/Users/Admin/Desktop/CardinalPGM-master/src/main/java/in/twizmwaz/cardinal/module/modules/projectiles/ProjectilesBuilder.java:[3,34] package in.parapengu.commons.utils does not exist
[ERROR] /c:/Users/Admin/Desktop/CardinalPGM-master/src/main/java/in/twizmwaz/cardinal/module/modules/regions/type/CuboidRegion.java:[3,34] package in.parapengu.commons.utils does not exist
[ERROR] /c:/Users/Admin/Desktop/CardinalPGM-master/src/main/java/in/twizmwaz/cardinal/module/modules/toolRepair/ToolRepairBuilder.java:[3,34] package in.parapengu.commons.utils does not exist
[ERROR] /c:/Users/Admin/Desktop/CardinalPGM-master/src/main/java/in/twizmwaz/cardinal/module/modules/regions/type/SphereRegion.java:[3,34] package in.parapengu.commons.utils does not exist
[ERROR] /c:/Users/Admin/Desktop/CardinalPGM-master/src/main/java/in/twizmwaz/cardinal/module/modules/team/TeamModuleBuilder.java:[3,34] package in.parapengu.commons.utils does not exist
[ERROR] /c:/Users/Admin/Desktop/CardinalPGM-master/src/main/java/in/twizmwaz/cardinal/module/modules/disableDamage/DisableDamageBuilder.java:[3,34] package in.parapengu.commons.utils does not exist
[ERROR] /c:/Users/Admin/Desktop/CardinalPGM-master/src/main/java/in/twizmwaz/cardinal/module/modules/wools/WoolObjective.java:[3,34] package in.parapengu.commons.utils does not exist
[ERROR] /c:/Users/Admin/Desktop/CardinalPGM-master/src/main/java/in/twizmwaz/cardinal/module/modules/regions/type/CylinderRegion.java:[57,20] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable OtherUtil
  location: class in.twizmwaz.cardinal.module.modules.regions.type.CylinderRegion
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the important bits:

```
[ERROR] error reading C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\in\parapengu\commons\1.1.2\commons-1.1.2.jar; error in opening zip file
[ERROR] error reading C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\com\comphenix\executors\BukkitExecutors\1.0.0\BukkitExecutors-1.0.0.jar; error in opening zip file
[ERROR] error reading C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\in\parapengu\commons\1.1.2\commons-1.1.2.jar; error in opening zip file
[ERROR] error reading C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\com\comphenix\executors\BukkitExecutors\1.0.0\BukkitExecutors-1.0.0.jar; error in opening zip file
```

That means Maven was unable to open those files. Reasons can be:

- No permission for this folder
- There is a corrupt file there

Delete the offending files and start Maven again. If it fails, don't blindly start it a second time but look in the output for errors.

Comment: Ok, this works fine for me. Now I can compile it perfectly. Thanks. Really helpful.